# Could not set unknown property 'applicationDefaultJvmArgs' in Gradle

Tags: java, spring, gradle

In file build.gradle of my Java project i add `applicationDefaultJvmArgs` as bellow

```
applicationDefaultJvmArgs = ['-Xmx512m', '-XX:MaxPermSize=512m', '-Dinm.testmode=true', '-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8', '-Xdebug','-Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,address=7979,suspend=n']
```

and i get error

```
Could not set unknown property 'applicationDefaultJvmArgs' for root project
```

How can i fix it ?

Comment: Can you please provide the build script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`applicationDefaultJvmArgs` is a property of the [Application Plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/application_plugin.html) and must be defined in the `application` configuration closure:

```
plugins {
    id 'application'
}

application {
    applicationDefaultJvmArgs = ['-Xmx512m', '-XX:MaxPermSize=512m', '-Dinm.testmode=true', '-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8', '-Xdebug','-Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,address=7979,suspend=n']
}
```

See the application plugin's [Usage](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/application_plugin.html#sec:application_usage) guide for more examples.